# How can we create a fake gps publisher node in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to create a fake GPS ros node to publish the GPS data so that the robot_localization package can subscribe to it for localization? What information would I be requiring for this task? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349587/how-can-we-create-a-fake-gps-publisher-node-in-ros2-?/) by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2020-04-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have put a node below that publishes static GPS data in a sensor_msgs/NavSatFix message to the topic 'gps/fix' since the navsat_transform_node of robot_localization subscribes to gps/fix. If you want the GPS data to update you can change the values on the attributes you need e.g. latitude/longitude over time in the pattern you want.

```
import rclpy
import os
from rclpy.node import Node

from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatStatus
from std_msgs.msg import Header


class GpsNode(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('gps_node')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(NavSatFix, 'gps/fix', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        
    def timer_callback(self):
            msg = NavSatFix()
            msg.header = Header()
            msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
            msg.header.frame_id = "gps"

            msg.status.status = NavSatStatus.STATUS_FIX
            msg.status.service = NavSatStatus.SERVICE_GPS

            # Position in degrees.
            msg.latitude = 57.047218
            msg.longitude = 9.920100
            
            # Altitude in metres.
            msg.altitude = 1.15
            
            msg.position_covariance[0] = 0
            msg.position_covariance[4] = 0
            msg.position_covariance[8] = 0
            msg.position_covariance_type = NavSatFix.COVARIANCE_TYPE_DIAGONAL_KNOWN
            
            self.publisher_.publish(msg)
            self.best_pos_a = None


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    gps_node = GpsNode()

    rclpy.spin(gps_node)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    gps_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [DanielRobotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/34746/danielrobotics/) with karma: 42 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-04-16**:
@DanielRobotics thanks for catching the duplicate post. Recently spammers are getting more sophisticated and will duplicate posts like this to make their accounts look more active.

**Comment by [Rika](https://answers.ros.org/users/75014/rika/) on 2021-08-07**:
Hi, thanks a lot for this but do you happen to know if this also works in ROS1?